# Mail crashing in High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app

2011 MacBook Pro running High Sierra. My Mail app crashes constantly, most frequently when I empty the trash bin or the junk mail. I have tried deleting the envelope files and preferences to no avail. Thoughts?

Comment: how many messages are in you mailbox and how much free space on your internal disk drive.

Comment: i suppose your using Apple Mail,

Comment: Yes, sorry...Apple Mail. 600GB on my HD, so that is fine, and I do a weekly purge of the newsletters and whatnot that come through, so right now I just have 60...

Comment: I have the log from the latest crash, which just happened... if I can figure out how to upload it...

Comment: to read the latest crash report go to the Applications/Utilities folder and open the console app. The reports are listed on the left side of the console screen that appears.  Click on the report you want to view and the console will show you the report. Every event is time-stamped.

Comment: yes, of course... I HAVE the console/log sheet from this morning... just not sure how to upload it here, for interpretation

Comment: oh sorry. i misunderstood what you were  asking.

Comment: You can select the lines you want to show and copy them from the console app. i'd then paste them into TextEdit.  To display on Ask Different you can paste the lines in.